# Post-processing of the image failed. If this is a photo or a large image, please scale it down to 2500 pixels and upload it again

Tags: image, post

Experiencing the error - "Post-processing of the image failed. If this is a photo or a large image, please scale it down to 2500 pixels and upload it again". May be this is happening for WordPress latest version update.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my website. I downgraded the WordPress version. That was a quick fix.

Comment: No one answered the question here. So, I did little research on it and find some possible solutions. [How to Solve Post Prepossessing Error](https://wppathfinder.com/post-processing-of-the-image-failed/)

Answer (score 0):

For me, disabling the Smush plugin worked. The files did get uploaded, it just didn't finish. I first removed the uploaded files in the `wp-content/upload` folder using FTP.